# Name for a refill on an entire funnel

Tags: navigation, seo

In SEO/UX/IA is there a term used to describe when a user enters a funnel (e.g. a Search) reaches the end of the funnel (e.g. results) and then repeats the process (e.g. starts another search).

In a micro level a form field being re-entered I refer to as a refill. So I'm looking for a similar term but for an entire funnel instead of just 1 single element.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about user experience.

Comment: user experience and analytics go hand in hand. If your not using analytics to aid your work then go back to being a web designer.

Comment: I am for keeping the question open. Ty Fairclough's question is about a special type of interaction, and everything in user experience is about the user interacting with the system. I can certainly imagine myself using such a term when discussing a possible interaction design of a system, and discussing such designs is one of the central part of our jobs in UX.

Comment: @TyFairclough - No need to be rude. You are looking for a *term*. Terms have nothing to do with user experience. That's all I'm saying. You could go to [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/) for terms.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the language and usage link I'm going to jump in there see if I can find anything that can help and share my findings here. We could argue forever the validity of terms, UX is a term to describe gracefully a compound meaning. We use terms every day in everything we do. I apologise for coming across strong I was frustrated at the push back without sound reasoning (this question did get removed from stack exchange but the validation for it was just so I was more than happy to delete it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [quite common in analytics and SEM](http://searchengineland.com/adwords-flexible-conversion-counting-officially-lauched-welcome-converted-clicks-conversions-185235) to distinguish between **unique** events and a total number of events.

As you're obviously tracking conversions (please note that a conversion doesn't always have to be a sale), I'd go with the term ***"Unique Conversions"*** to track the amount of different users that completed the funnel. ***"All Conversions"*** would give you the total amount and the difference between the two equals to the amount of users that went through the funnel multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "pogoing" or "pogosticking"?

> "We can define pogosticking as the average number of product detail
>   pages viewed on your site, divided by the number of unique search
>   queries ... "

http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/06/search-results-satori-balancing-pogosticking-and-page-relevance.php

Comment: That sounds like a sensible answer to my use case. Thanks for answering.